# How to stop the infinity slides in a very basic slider with li elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this basic slider for my registration form. [(Right here the original slider's Codepen)](http://codepen.io/GMK/pen/kxwKL)

This is how I control the slide:
(I use a variable to track where is the user, this is panel.)

```
// previous
    $('.navTitle a').click(function () {
        if (panel !== 1){
            moveLeft();
        }
    });

// next
$('#reg-userNextBtn').click(function () {
    if (panel !== max) {
        moveRight();
    }           
});
```

The bug I found is that if you click very fast, you can go around this "control" thing and the slider became infinity, you can walk through on any li element which is bad if you're trying to make a registration form that has separated parts.

I assume the problem lays here:

(after left move animation)

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
$('#slider ul').css('left', '');
```

(after right move animation)

```
$('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
$('#slider ul').css('left', '');
```

(and in the beginning of the slider)

```
$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
```

I tell the truth I understand the whole slider except this part. How could I solve this issue? I'd like to have the same behavior, just without this little bug.

Comment: "I tell the truth I understand the whole slider except this part" ... Prove it. StackOverflow is about transparency and honest programmers.

Comment: Is the problem that it keeps sliding if you click it more than once?

Comment: Yes, but party. It's working fine if you click slowly, and actually it's working fine if you click fast on any part of the slider except the last and the first elements. Then it doesn't listen to the condition. If you are clicking quickly on the previous button and you stop clicking on the first element, then a second later you click on the previous button again, the condition works.. if you don't stop, then it goes into infinity sliding, I mean you can go around the whole li elements. So it seems like you click too fast that the condition to be executed.

Comment: Well now I tried an other thing, when you are on the form's slide, js makes the next button inactive... normally, but if you click really fast you can avoid this, too. :/ Is my condition this bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide the next/previous buttons while the animation works and show it at finish.

```
function move(lOr){   //this function replaces moveLeft and moveRight
    $("a[class^=control_]").hide(0);

    var direction = (lOr === 'left') ? '+'+slideWidth : '-'+slideWidth;
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: direction
    }, 500, function () {
        switch(lOr)
        {
          case 'left':
              $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
          break;
          default:
              $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
          break;
        }            
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        $("a[class^=control_]").show(0);
    });
}

$('a.control_prev').click(function () {
    move('left');
});

$('a.control_next').click(function () {
    move('right');
});
```

});

See this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JcfKa).

**Edit:**

Instead of hidding the buttons, you could disable/enable them:

```
function move(lOr){   //this function replaces moveLeft and moveRight
    $("a[class^=control_]").unbind("click");
....

....
    $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
          move('left');
    });
    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
          move('right');
    });
....
```

Comment: I already finished the whole registration process, so I might won't replace now everything, but I'll try this show/hide trick and will give you feedback in a few minutes. :) Thanks!

Comment: It's working fine, but looking ugly on my design. I'll try to make the move events somehow with setTimeout 1s maybe. Thanks for the answer, this is what I needed, a little push, a little guideline. :)

Comment: @ThePianist You could also disable/enable the buttons instead of hidding/showing them. Have a look at the edit. (Codepen also edited).

Comment: I'll give you the accepted answer, because I appreciate your help, but I'll post my version, too. I solved it after your post. :)

Answer (score 0):

After @ojovirtual's post, I tried several things again and I successfully solved my problem.

I use a helper variable, called `mehet` (default: true) and I change it's boolean value before and after the animation, then use it in the condition on click.

```
function moveRight() {

        mehet = false;

        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
            }, 300, function () {

                mehet = true;
```

...

```
function moveLeft() {

    mehet = false;

    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: + slideWidth
        }, 300, function () {

            mehet = true;
```

...

And the modified conditions:

```
// previous btn
    $('.navTitle a').click(function () {  
            if ((panel !== 1) && (mehet === true)){    
                    moveLeft();   
            }            
    });

// next btn
$('#reg-userNextBtn').click(function () {

        if ((panel !== max) && (mehet === true)) {
                moveRight();
        }  
});
```